# Something unclear in this shared_ptr example

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class implementation
{
public:
    ~implementation() { std::cout <<"destroying implementation\n"; }
    void do_something() { std::cout << "did something\n"; }
};

void test()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<implementation> sp1(new implementation());
    std::cout<<"The Sample now has "<<sp1.use_count()<<" references\n";

    boost::shared_ptr<implementation> sp2 = sp1;
    std::cout<<"The Sample now has "<<sp2.use_count()<<" references\n";

    sp1.reset();
    std::cout<<"After Reset sp1. The Sample now has "<<sp2.use_count()<<" references\n";

    sp2.reset();
    std::cout<<"After Reset sp2.\n";
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

The running result is below:

```
$ ./a.out 
The Sample now has 1 references
The Sample now has 2 references
After Reset sp1. The Sample now has 1 references
destroying implementation
After Reset sp2.
```

Please check the above code. The first thing unclear to me is that what does below sentence mean? So sp1 is a pointer? a function? or a pointer to a function? and `new implementation()` means what? The argument of sp1()?

```
boost::shared_ptr<implementation> sp1(new implementation());
```

The second question is that `destroying implementation` is given as a result of `sp1.reset()` and `sp2.reset()`. But if `sp1.reset()` is commented out, then the result will be:

```
$ ./a.out 
The Sample now has 1 references
The Sample now has 2 references
After Reset sp1. The Sample now has 2 references
After Reset sp2.
destroying implementation
```

If we only comment out `sp2.reset()`, then the result will be:

```
$ ./a.out 
The Sample now has 1 references
The Sample now has 2 references
After Reset sp1. The Sample now has 1 references
After Reset sp2.
destroying implementation
```

So it is not necessary to call both `sp1.reset()` and `sp2.reset()` to release the shared_ptr, am I right?

Comment: You don't need to call `reset` to release the pointer **at all**, you use `reset` to change what the smart pointer is currently pointing to. Think of it as you would think of the assignment operator for a regular pointer.

Comment: If you don't know what `new x()` does, you need to learn about pointers. If you don't know what a shared pointer is, you need to learn about smart pointers. There's no easy answer that will be more beneficial than actually reading up on them.

Comment: It's also at least conceivable that you ought to be learning another language first, before trying to understand C++ `shared_ptr`. It's a lot easier to explain it in terms of "what Python does automatically" or "a cleaner and more readable idiom to do the same thing `try`/`finally` does in language X" than to explain it from scratch…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first thing unclear to me is that what does below sentence mean? So sp1 is a pointer? a function? or a pointer to a function?

`sp` is a `shared_ptr<implementation>`. If you don't know what that means, there's reference documentation and tutorials to look at. But the short version is: it's an object that acts similar to an `implementation *` pointer, except that it automatically deletes the `implementation` object whne you're done with it. That's what makes it a "smart pointer". A `shared_ptr` is a specific kind of smart pointer that lets you make as many copies as you want, and only deletes the underlying object when all of those copies go away.

One way to look as this is that it gives you a simple form of garbage collection that doesn't require a garbage collector.

Another way to look at it is as part of [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (RAII), one of the central idioms of C++.

> and new implementation() means what? The argument of sp1()?

`new implementation()` creates a new `implementation` object, calls its default constructor, and returns an `implementation *` pointer. That pointer is the argument to the `shared_ptr` constructor. This means that `sp1` becomes a smart pointer to that new `implementation` object, so that object will be destroyed and deleted when `sp1`, and any copies later made of it, all go away.

> The second question is that destroying implementation is given as a result of sp1.reset() and sp2.reset().

Actually, it's given as a result of both `sp1` and `sp2` being pointed at new values *or* being destroyed. `reset` does the former, but just doing nothing and letting them go out of scope does the latter. That's a major part of what RAII is all about.

> So it is not necessary to call both sp1.reset() and sp2.reset() to release the shared_ptr, am I right?

Exactly. You very rarely want to explicitly call `reset`. The whole point of RAII is that you don't have to manage these things manually; you initialize an object (like a `shared_ptr`) to acquire access to a resource, and just let that object go away to release access.

There are a few cases where it's useful. For example, if you have a `shared_ptr` as a member of an object, and that object is going to last much longer than the resource it owns, you can release it early by calling `reset`. (And if you've passed a copy off to someone else in the meantime, you don't have to worry about it being deleted early—it just means that you're no longer involved in keeping it alive.)

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, there are some fundamentals to be learned off the SO format.

However, the last question deserves an answer:

> So it is not necessary to call both sp1.reset() and sp2.reset() to release the shared_ptr, am I right?

The reason you see the implementation destructed if you reset only one of your pointers is due to end of scope, i.e. returning from `test()` - causing your `shared_ptr`s to go out of scope and be destroyed, leading consequently to the destruction of managed objecsts.

Comment: No, it's _not_ "end of program", it's "end of the scope `sp1` and `sp2` were defined in", which is the `test` function. If `shared_ptr`s didn't delete objects until the end of the program, there would be much less point to them, because all memory gets freed anyway when the program ends. (Of course that's "less point", not "no point", because sometimes the destructors will do more than just free memory.)